# Text rendering issue with starling framework

Tags: flash, starling-framework, visual-glitch, feathers-ui

I'm using the feathers/starling framework and I've noticed that on some machines there's a rendering issue (illustration attached). The bitmap font is rendered with some glitches. I've made tests in latest Chrome with the latest Flash player on Windows and Debian machines. On Debian everything is rendered fine, on Windows the glitch is present only on one machine. What can be the source of the issue? Many Windows users reported this issue to me too.

You can notice that same letters are sometimes rendered fine and sometimes not.

I'm not sure if this is related, but on the Windows machine which has glitches there's also a issue when the FPS can not go over 5 or maybe 10 for no reason. This issue is always reported by users in couple with the first one.

P.S. The font size used inside the application is the very same as used while exporting from the converter.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used to create bitmap fonts with [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)
and I had this problem with Persian fonts.

Changing the rasterization option to font smoothing or thickness solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be an issue with windows 10 app scaling? I've seen similar things on non-flash apps on my win10 HTPC depending on what I have the resolution and scaling set to.  Or maybe browser zoom level?